# Disable IPv6 using CMD or Powershell on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, powershell, ipv6

I'm trying to disable IPv6 connectivity on Windows using either command line or WMI api without restarting the computer (I know about adding an entry into Windows registry, but this requires rebooting the machine so it is not suitable). I know that unchecking `ipv6` option in network adapter immediately disables it and I was able to achieve this via powershell commands such as `Disable-NetAdapterBinding` on newer Windows (8, 10) but Powershell on my Win7 VM reports `unrecognized command` for this. So the question is - is there another way to achieve the same thing (unchecking `ipv6` option in network adapter) in `Win7` using CMD or Powershell?

P.S. Disabling `teredo`, `6to4` and `isatap` via netsh utility also doesn't work for me.

Comment: Okay, so be sure to run your PowerShell terminal/shell session and/or your cmd session elevated running as administrator running the same commands. What is your result?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT started my cmd as administrator, tried netsh commands - they all printed OK, but I was still able to use IPv6 (also tried with powershell - same result) - probably I have native IPv6 support fro my provider. So is there another way to uncheck IPv6 option on network adapter?

Comment: FYI... ['windows don't disable ipv6'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+don%27t+disable+ipv6&form=ANNTH1&refig=10d4e5a7fd9944029daade32466fc167&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=windows+don%27t+disable+ipv6&sc=1-26&qs=n&sk=&cvid=10d4e5a7fd9944029daade32466fc167)

Comment: @postanote 
I know that Microsoft does not recommend disabling it, but I'm required to do so.